# Scrapy - Adding a table header (thead) value to Item Loader

Tags: python, scrapy

I have a webpage that contains multiple tables that I wish to scrape using Scrapy:

```
<table>
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>
            <a>Heading1</a>
         </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <th>Col1</th>
         <th>Col2</th>
         <th>Col3</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td><a href="#">Name1</a></td>
         <td>Description1</td>
         <td>Number1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td><a href="#">Name2</a></td>
         <td>Description2</td>
         <td>Number2</td>
      </tr>

      ...

    </tbody>
</table>
```

There are many tables like the above on the one page.

I am using an Item Loader to store the data from looping through each row, grabbing the:

- Name
- Description
- Number

The Scrapy spider is the following:

```
class MySpider(BaseSpider):
   ...

   def parse(self, response):
      hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
      tb = hxs.xpath('//table')

      for td in tb.xpath('.//tbody/tr'):
         il = WebsiteLoader(response=response, selector=td)

         il.add_xpath('name', 'td/a/text()')
         il.add_xpath('description', 'td[1]/text()')
         il.add_xpath('number', 'td[2]/text()')

         yield il.load_item()
```

This works great, and I can get my Item Loader populated with each row of data, on all of the instances of the same table on the page.

However, my question is:

> **How can I add a 4th field to my Item Loader, that contains the 'Heading' text for each table that I scrape?**

Thank you for your help in advance!

---

**EDIT**

This is a sample of the data I can currently scrape:

```
Name1 | Description1 | Number1
Name2 | Description2 | Number2
...

# and so forth for the other table instances:

Name3 | Description3 | Number3
Name4 | Description4 | Number4
...
```

And this is what I would like to have:

```
Name1 | Description1 | Number1 | Heading1
Name2 | Description2 | Number2 | Heading1
...

# and so forth for the other table instances:

Name3 | Description3 | Number3 | Heading2
Name4 | Description4 | Number4 | Heading2
...
```

Comment: Anybody can help me with this issue?

Comment: hard to understand what you are trying to achieve, heading is per table and you ask for a 4th field for your items? do you wish to repeat the headings in all items as a 4th field? and if so, how will you put say... 4 headings in a single field on the item? comma separated...

Comment: @Guy Thank you for replying. Each table has isn't own separate header, and I'm scraping the data to a database. Each row I would like to add a 4th field of the heading to it's record. So yes I would like to repeat the heading.

Comment: pls add an example of how will a full item should look like, including that 4th field

Comment: @Guy Thank you Guy, I have edited my original submission with my scraped data set I currently have and what I would like.

Comment: so, given the table html you shared, what will be HeadingX? `Heading1,Col1,Col2,Col3` repeated on each row (item) of that table?

Comment: @Guy If there are 3 tables on a page, there will be `Heading1`, `Heading2` and `Heading3` - one heading for each table. The `Col1,Col2,Col3` are consistent for each table and are ignored.

Comment: @Guy Note there are multiple instances of the table code I supplied on the one page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope I understand correctly, maybe something like:

```
def parse(self, response):
   hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
   for tb in hxs.xpath('//table'):

       heading = tb.xpath('.//thead/tr/th/a/text()').extract()[0]

       for td in tb.xpath('.//tbody/tr'):
          il = WebsiteLoader(response=response, selector=td)
          ...
          il.add_value('heading', heading)
          yield il.load_item()
```

Comment: Great now I have the first heading, `Heading1`, assigned - thank you! However, the value doesn't change to `Heading2` for the next table, instead using the same `Heading1` value. This is where I am currently stuck.

Comment: Thank you very much! I did have an index out of range error, but I think there was a phantom table being picked up, so I changed it to the table class I wanted and it works a treat!

Comment: I guess one/some of your tables lack this structure, hard to tell without seeing the real html page, try to print `tb.xpath('.//thead/').extract()` and see

Comment: I edited my comment - there was another table that wasn't like the others being picked up as well - Thank you very, very much for helping me :)